# How to Test Kafka Consumer

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka Consumer (built in Scala) which extracts latest records from Kafka. The consumer looks like this:

```
val consumerProperties = new Properties()
consumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
consumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
consumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
consumerProperties.put("group.id", "something")
consumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset", "latest")

val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](consumerProperties)
consumer.subscribe(java.util.Collections.singletonList("topic"))
```

Now, I want to write an integration test for it. Is there any way or any best practice for Testing Kafka Consumers?

Answer (score 6):

1. You need to start zookeeper and kafka programmatically for integration tests.

   **1.1 start zookeeper (`ZooKeeperServer`)**

   ```
   def startZooKeeper(zooKeeperPort: Int, zkLogsDir: Directory): ServerCnxnFactory = {
       val tickTime = 2000

       val zkServer = new ZooKeeperServer(zkLogsDir.toFile.jfile, zkLogsDir.toFile.jfile, tickTime)

       val factory = ServerCnxnFactory.createFactory
       factory.configure(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0", zooKeeperPort), 1024)
       factory.startup(zkServer)

       factory
   }
   ```

   **1.2 start kafka (`KafkaServer`)**

   ```
   case class StreamConfig(streamTcpPort: Int = 9092,
                       streamStateTcpPort :Int = 2181,
                       stream: String,
                       numOfPartition: Int = 1,
                       nodes: Map[String, String] = Map.empty)

   def startKafkaBroker(config: StreamConfig,
                      kafkaLogDir: Directory): KafkaServer = {

     val syncServiceAddress = s"localhost:${config.streamStateTcpPort}"

     val properties: Properties = new Properties
     properties.setProperty("zookeeper.connect", syncServiceAddress)
     properties.setProperty("broker.id", "0")
     properties.setProperty("host.name", "localhost")
     properties.setProperty("advertised.host.name", "localhost")
     properties.setProperty("port", config.streamTcpPort.toString)
     properties.setProperty("auto.create.topics.enable", "true")
     properties.setProperty("log.dir", kafkaLogDir.toAbsolute.path)
     properties.setProperty("log.flush.interval.messages", 1.toString)
     properties.setProperty("log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size", "1048577")

     config.nodes.foreach {
       case (key, value) => properties.setProperty(key, value)
     }

     val broker = new KafkaServer(new KafkaConfig(properties))
     broker.startup()

     println(s"KafkaStream Broker started at ${properties.get("host.name")}:${properties.get("port")} at ${kafkaLogDir.toFile}")
     broker
   ```

   }
2. emit some events to stream using `KafkaProducer`
3. Then consume with your **consumer to test** and verify its working

You can use [scalatest-eventstream](https://github.com/duwamish-os/scalatest-eventstream/blob/master/src/main/scala/org/scalatest/eventstream/kafka/KafkaEmbeddedStream.scala) that has `startBroker` method which will start Zookeeper and Kafka for you.

Also has `destroyBroker` which will cleanup your kafka after tests.

eg.

```
class MyStreamConsumerSpecs extends FunSpec with BeforeAndAfterAll with Matchers {
  implicit val config =
    StreamConfig(streamTcpPort = 9092, streamStateTcpPort = 2181, stream = "test-topic", numOfPartition = 1)

  val kafkaStream = new KafkaEmbeddedStream

  override protected def beforeAll(): Unit = {
    kafkaStream.startBroker
  }

  override protected def afterAll(): Unit = {
    kafkaStream.destroyBroker
  }

  describe("Kafka Embedded stream") {
    it("does consume some events") {

      //uses application.properties
      //emitter.broker.endpoint=localhost:9092
      //emitter.event.key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      //emitter.event.value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
      kafkaStream.appendEvent("test-topic", """{"MyEvent" : { "myKey" : "myValue"}}""")

      val consumerProperties = new Properties()
      consumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
      consumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
      consumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
      consumerProperties.put("group.id", "something")
      consumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset", "earliest")

      val myConsumer = new KafkaConsumer[String, String](consumerProperties)
      myConsumer.subscribe(java.util.Collections.singletonList("test-topic"))

      val events = myConsumer.poll(2000)

      events.count() shouldBe 1
      events.iterator().next().value() shouldBe """{"MyEvent" : { "myKey" : "myValue"}}"""
      println("=================" + events.count())
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I have one doubt here. The Kafka Consumer I want to test has `auto.offset.reset` as `latest`, not `earliest`. Due to which, when I tried the above mentioned solution, the consumer is not able to receive any message. Can you please mention how to test a Kafka Consumer with `latest` offset ?

Comment: In above example I'm emitting event first and then starting a consumer, thats why I'm processing from `earliest`. If you want to process the `latest`, start the consumer first and emit event, it will process the event. See example - https://github.com/duwamish-os/scalatest-eventstream/blob/master/src/test/scala/org/scalatest/eventstream/kafka/KafkaEmbeddedStreamSpecs.scala#L55 Also, you will have to poll from stream in a loop

Comment: To add more when you configure latest, it means consumer will process messages which are emitted only after the consumer was started.

Comment: I am using this method, but when I execute this code, it runs without ending. The producer does something (I add log) but it seems that the consumer is not executed. Any idea ?